# Parallel.ForEach error HttpContext.Current

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, parallel-processing

this method - `doDayBegin(item.BranchId)` is taking long time to execute. So I am using `Parallel.ForEach` to execute it parallel. When I am using normal `foreach` loop its working fine but when i am using `Parallel.ForEach` it showing this error

**Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

```
 public ActionResult Edit([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
        {
            try
            {
                JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                List<DB0010020Vm> _listDB0010020Vm = new List<DB0010020Vm>();

                string dataDB0010020vm = Request.Form["griddetailsvm"];
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dataDB0010020vm))
                {
                    _listDB0010020Vm = js.Deserialize<List<DB0010020Vm>>(dataDB0010020vm).
                    Where(d => d.IsValid == "YES").ToList();
                }
                DateTime start = DateTime.UtcNow;


                Parallel.ForEach(_listDB0010020Vm, item =>
                {
                    doDayBegin(item.BranchId);
                });

                DateTime end = DateTime.UtcNow;
                TimeSpan duration = end - start;
                return Json(new
                {
                    success = true,
                    message = "Day Begin Process Completed Successfully!" + duration
                });
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return Json(new
                {
                    success = false,
                    message = e.Message
                });

            }
        }

  public void doDayBegin(int BranchId)
{
    var httpContext = System.Web.HttpContext.Current;
    IDB0010020Repository _idDB0010020Repository = new DB0010020Repository();
    IDB0010044Repository _idDB0010044Repository = new DB0010044Repository();

     EBS.DAL.Model.DB0010020 branchDetails = _idDB0010020Repository.FindOne(d => d.BranchId == BranchId);
    if (branchDetails == null)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Branch not found!");
    }
    else
    {
        try
        {
            DateTime LastOpenDate = DateTime.ParseExact(Request.Form["LastOpenDate"].ToString(), "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
         //   branchDetails.LastOpenDate = LastOpenDate;
    //      branchDetails.LastOpenDate = Convert.ToDateTime(Request.Form["LastOpenDate"].ToString());


        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
          //  branchDetails.LastOpenDate = Convert.ToDateTime("2014-07-25 00:00:00.000");
        }


        OperationStatus status = _idDB0010020Repository.UpdateAndSave(branchDetails);
        if (status != null && !status.Status)
            ModelState.AddModelError("Updation failed", status.ExceptionMessage);
    }

    EBS.DAL.Model.DB0010044 dayBegin = new DB0010044();
    dayBegin.BankId = 1;
    dayBegin.BranchId = BranchId;
    dayBegin.DayBeginFlag = 1;
    //added d
    DateTime DayDate = DateTime.ParseExact(Request.Form["LastOpenDate"].ToString(), "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    dayBegin.DayDate = DayDate;
    //added d

  //  dayBegin.DayDate = Convert.ToDateTime(Request.Form["LastOpenDate"]);
    dayBegin.DayEndFlag = 0;
    dayBegin.DayEndStage = 1;
    dayBegin.DayReopenFlag = 0;
    OperationStatus status2 = _idDB0010044Repository.AddAndSave(dayBegin);
    if (status2 != null && !status2.Status)
        ModelState.AddModelError("Updation failed", status2.ExceptionMessage);
    else
    {
        CreateInwardSessionsForBranch(BranchId);
        CreateOutwardSessionsForBranch(BranchId);
    }

}
```

this is error
[image: this error i am getting]

**what will be the issue? why i am getting Session null. what is way to solve it**

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`HttpContext.Current` is set per thread. So when you fire up more threads using `Parallel.ForEach` your new threads can't access it that way. The solution would be to pass the needed values as parameters all the way instead of relying on `HttpContext.Current` in your repositories.

There are several sources here on SO that covers this problem already.

[The cross-thread usage of "HttpContext.Current" property and related things](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8109526/the-cross-thread-usage-of-httpcontext-current-property-and-related-things)

[HttpContext.Current.Items in different thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15196556/httpcontext-current-items-in-different-thread)

[Access HttpContext.Current from different threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8925227/access-httpcontext-current-from-threads)

Answer (score 2):

You get the error because you are trying to get the `HttpContext` from a thread that is not running for the purpose of responding to a request.

The `HttpContext.Current` property uses the thread to identify which context to get, as the web server can run several threads to handle requests. As the `Parallel.ForEach` starts new threads, they will not be connected to a `HttpContext`.

You need to pass along the information that the method needs in the call to the method.

Answer (score 2):

HttpContext.Current is null because it's running in "non-web threads". If you forked some code using new Thread(...) it would be exactly the same. The TPL somewhat hides this, but you still need to realize that each iteration in your Parallel.ForEach can potentially run in a different thread, and treat it accordingly.

In particular, if you want to use some class or method out of the web request (and Parallel.ForEach is such an usage) you just can't use HttpContext.Current. A workaround is to explicitly pass the HttpContext (or HttpContextBase for improved testability) in the constructor (or as a method parameter)

example :

```
var context = HttpContext.Current;
Parallel.ForEach(items, item =>
    {
        DoSomething(context);
    }
);



private static void DoSomething(HttpContext context) {
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Further adding to Bayu Alvian answer. I had a similar problem and I solved it by passing the context as parameter but inside the method I got

Member 'method name' cannot be accessed with an instance reference

I solved it by doing a little tweak from the above answer.

```
// Get the new context
HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
Parallel.ForEach(items, item =>
    {
        DoSomething(context);
    }
);

private static void DoSomething(HttpContext context) {
 HttpContext.Current = context;
}
```

Assigning the context to the HttpContext.Current removes it.