# Spawn new thread inside each foreach(), but do not return until all complete

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a `foreach()` that loops through 15 reports and generates a PDF for each. The PDF generation process is slow (3 seconds each). But if I could generate them all concurrently with threads, maybe all 15 could be done in 4-5 seconds total. One constraint is that the function must not return until ALL pdfs have generated. Also, will 15 concurrent worker threads cause problems or instability for dotnet/windows?

Here is my pseudocode:

```
private void makePDFs(string path) {
  string[] folders = Directory.GetDirectories(path);

  foreach(string folderPath in folders) {
     generatePDF(...);   
   }

   // DO NOT RETURN UNTIL ALL PDFs HAVE BEEN GENERATED
 }
}
```

What is the simplest way to achieve this?

Comment: are you looking for `Thread.Join`?

Comment: `await Task.WhenAll(yourTaskList)`

Comment: My question went from +3 to -1 in 2 hours. And no comments as to why.

Comment: I must caution you against parallel processing on ASP.NET. Unless you're *sure* that the number of simultaneous users will always be very low, you can easily bring your server to its knees.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most straightforward approach is to use [Parallel.ForEach](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

```
private void makePDFs(string path)
{
    string[] folders = Directory.GetDirectories(path);

    Parallel.ForEach(folders, (folderPath)  => 
      {
          generatePDF(folderPath);   
      };

    //WILL NOT RETURN UNTIL ALL PDFs HAVE BEEN GENERATED
}
```

This way you avoid having to create, keep track of, and await each separate task; the [TPL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-parallel-library-tpl) does it all for you.

Comment: John, this looks promising, but inside my generatePDF() function is a call to HttpContext.Current, which is null when inside the context of Parallel.ForEach(). When I run it the old (slow) way, I'm able to reference this object without errors. Any ideas?

Comment: You've run into [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26710980/parallel-foreach-error-httpcontext-current). What data elements do you need from `HttpContext`?

Comment: When I pass in HtttpContext things go wrong, even though it's not null, the same context keeps getting reused, and the URL that the PDF generator points to seems to be the same each time. I'm going to accept your answer and open a new question, because it's tangential now at this point. At the core, Parallel.ForEach() does its job nicely!

Comment: I wouldn't try to clone HttpContext. Instead, extract the values you need as primitive types, e.g. if you need to know a cookie value, extract it in the main thread and pass it as a string. HttpContext is bound to the thread (sort of, it's complicated).

Comment: It's not a matter of getting values, but more a matter of needing to run `Server.Execute()` inside the worker threads. I just wrote up the whole issue here, would love if you could take a peek: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46248148/how-to-safely-use-server-execute-inside-a-worker-thread

Answer (score 2):

You need to get a list of tasks and then use `Task.WhenAll` to wait for completion

```
var tasks = folders.Select(folder => Task.Run(() => generatePDF(...)));
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

If you can't or don't want to use `async/await` you can use:

```
Task.WaitAll(tasks);
```

It will block current thread until all tasks are completed. So I'd recommend to use the 1st approach if you can.

---

You can also run your PDF generation in parallel using `Parallel` C# class:

```
Parallel.ForEach(folders, folder => generatePDF(...));
```

Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5009224/2061604) to choose which approach works the best for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

.NET has a handy method just for this: `Task.WhenAll(IEnumerable<Task>)`
It will wait for all tasks in the IEnumerable to finish before continuing. It is an `async` method, so you need to `await` it.

```
var tasks = new List<Task>();
foreach(string folderPath in folders) {
    tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => generatePdf()));
}
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Comment: Kyle, Task.Run() requires 1 or more params. There are 8 overloads for this and none are void. The first option is a param of type `Action`. What exactly should I be passing in there? Can you show sample code?

Comment: You can pass it a function. From @Andrei : `Task.Run(() => generatePdf())`. I updated my answer to clarify.